# Plot numerical solutions for a varying parameter

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerical-value

I would like to solve this equation

$\log{\frac{a}{1 - a}} + b (1 - 2 a) = 0$

letting varying the parameter $b$ in $\lbrace 0,1,\ldots,20\rbrace$ and then plot the result.

I am trying writing the code but I am stuck with this

```
eq = Log[a/(1 - a)] + b (1 - 2 a) == 0
x = Range[1, 20, 1]
y = x
For[i = 1, i <= Length[x], i++, y[[i]] = NSolve[eq[a, b ./ b -> x[[i]]], a]]
```

but the syntax is wrong.
How can I do my plot? Thanks.

Comment: What should the correct code do? Independently of `b`, `a=1/2` is a solution. If `b` is an integer greater or equal to 2, there are additional real solutions. Which solutions do you need?

Comment: I should have been more precise. I am interested in the case $b>2$ and $a\neq \frac{1}{2}$. In the case $b > 2$ the solutions $a = \frac{1}{2}$ are always local maximums, I want to find the two global minimums.

Answer (score 2):

I post for insights. By inspection a=1/2 is always a real solution. For insight into the other solutions that vary with b:

```
f[a_, b_] := Log[a/(1 - a)] + b (1 - 2 a)
cp = ContourPlot[f[y, x], {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0.001, 0.999}, 
   Contours -> {{0.}}, ContourShading -> None, PlotPoints -> 50];
pp = Plot3D[f[y, x], {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0.001, 0.999}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0.}}, MeshStyle -> {Red, Thick},
    PlotPoints -> 50];
sol[b_] := 
  Chop[(a /. 
       Quiet[FindRoot[f[a, b] == 0, {a, #}, 
         AccuracyGoal -> Infinity]]) & /@ {0.0001, 0.5, 0.9999}];
rt = ListPlot[Transpose[Table[sol[j], {j, 0, 20, 0.5}]], 
   Joined -> True, Frame -> True];
Column[{cp, pp, rt}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let

```
eq = Log[a/(1 - a)] + b (1 - 2 a) == 0
```

First, at all cost don't use `For`. This is a topic way too broad and extensively covered on this site, so I'll just state it: don't use `For`, use `Do`, `While`, `Table`, ...

In this case I'll use `Table`.

Next, `NSolve` tries to find all solutions, which is usually hard. That's why I plotted the function `Log[a/(1 - a)] + b (1 - 2 a)` for a few `b` to see what to expect. This allowed me to set a starting point for `FindRoot`: the solutions will be near 0 and 1 (in fact, the greater `b` will be, the closer the solutions will be to 0 or 1).

To find solutions near `a=1`:

```
a1 = SetAccuracy[Chop@Table[{i, a /. FindRoot[eq /. b -> i, {a, 0.9999}]}, {i, 3, 
20}], 15]
```

> {{3.00000000000000, 0.92927981832006}, {4.000000000000000, 
>     0.97875201203864},...}

up to `b=20`.

Similarly, to find the other solution:

```
a0 = SetAccuracy[Chop@Table[{i, a /. FindRoot[eq /. b -> i, {a, 0.0000001}]}, {i, 3, 
20}], 15]
```

> {{3.00000000000000, 0.07072018167994}, {4.000000000000000, 
>     0.02124798796136},...}

also up to `b=20`.

To plot the solutions in dependence on `b`:

```
GraphicsRow[{ListPlot[a1, Frame -> True], ListPlot[a0, Frame -> True]}, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]